# angular : I want an angular build. But there's an error

Tags: angular, build

I want to upload my Angular project on the server.
However, "ng build" results in an error.

```
**The build command requires to be run in an Angular project, but a project definition could not be found.**
```

Comment: share you angular.json file or folder structure if you have changed, and make sure you are running this command in right context

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems you try to run `ng build` outside an angular project. Navigate to your project root and try again. From the [docs](https://angular.io/cli/build):

> Must be executed from within a workspace directory.